Maximum decrease in entropy per unit of energy?
They say we can decrease the entropy of a system by doing work. For example, this online physics text states, near Eq. 15.6.26, that: "If I pick up marbles that are scattered about the room and put them into a cup, my work has decreased the entropy of that system." (Emphasis added.)
So is there a theoretical maximum decrease in entropy we can achieve per unit of energy used to do work?

*"They say we can decrease the entropy of a system by doing work." Who says that? Can you please cite to a source, so we have some more context for your question?

@hft, I was reading this, just after equation 15.6.26: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/College_Physics/College_Physics_1e_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Thermodynamics/15.06%3A_Entropy_and_the_Second_Law_of_Thermodynamics-_Disorder_and_the_Unavailability_of_Energy

Thanks, I added that to the body of the question since comments may get deleted.


They say we can decrease the entropy of a system by doing work.

The only way the entropy of a system can decrease is by transferring heat to its surroundings. This occurs, for example, for reversible isothermal compression work on an ideal gas. Note, however, it is not the work itself that results in the decrease, it is the heat transfer associated with the work that results in the decrease. For example, If the compression work was reversible and adiabatic there would be no change in system entropy since there is no heat transfer to the surroundings.
Hope this helps.

I see your point. I didn't specify the work done in my question, because I was looking for a theoretical maximum. But I guess, theoretically, entropy can decrease with no work at all.

@RogerKeays More that theoretically. In the absence of any work, the ONLY way entropy of a system can decrease is by heat. The point is, work alone (in the absence of heat) cannot cause the entropy of a system to decrease.

How does this work in an endothermic chemical reaction? The products have lower entropy (more free energy) than the reactants, but the reaction absorbs heat from the surroundings.

@RogerKeays I’m not conversant in chemical thermodynamics but it’s my understanding that an endothermic chemical reaction is an irreversible process. That being the case, since the entropy of the system increases due to heat transfer in, the entropy of the surroundings must decrease by a lesser amount due to heat out-so that the total entropy change is greater than zero per the second law.
